# How to improve running time of mysql query that have INNER JOIN and Like search

Tags: mysql, indexing, query-optimization

Below is the query added by me, But it took say 0.35 second, Thoulgh it is not a large value, I am worried that the same query can cause memmory and processor load when the traffic is high on the website

```
SELECT count(P.id) as total FROM pages P
       INNER JOIN users U ON U.id = p.user_id
       INNER JOIN events E ON P.id = E.page_id
       WHERE (P.name LIKE '%keyword%' OR U.name LIKE '%keyword%') AND E.date > '2023-01-01';
```

The above mysql query took 0.35 seconds

But If I run the below query without JOIN it took only 0.02 seconds

> SELECT count(P.id) as total FROM pages P

Note: I have indexed user_id on pages table & page_id in events table

Is there any way to otimise the above query to get the correct result with less running time

Comment: Please update your question with the row counts and `CREATE TABLE` statements for these tables. Is `E.id = E.page_id` intentional or should it be `P.id = E.page_id`? Some sample data and examples of the `keyword` values might be helpful, too.

Comment: @user1191247 Yes it is `P.id = E.page_id`, I have updated the question. Regarding the sample data : I guess my question itself is self explanatory, My issue happens for table with large dataset like millions of rows, that is the reason why I didn't add the details about the database

Answer (score 1):

`LIKE` with a *leading* wildcard cannot use an index.  So, it will be slow.

Adding a `FULLTEXT(name)` index will make the search for *words* much faster:

```
WHERE MATCH(events.name) AGAINST('keyword' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

But only one table at a time.  So also use the `UNION` technique suggested by Ajimi.

Answer (score 0):

**Add Indexes:**
Since you have already indexed the user_id on the pages table and page_id in the events table, you can add an index on the date column in the events table. This can improve the performance of the query by making the data retrieval faster.

**Use subqueries instead of JOINs:**
Using subqueries instead of joins can sometimes lead to better performance. You can rewrite the query as follows:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(id) AS total FROM pages WHERE id IN (
  SELECT page_id FROM events WHERE date > '2023-01-01'
) AND name LIKE '%keyword%'
UNION
SELECT COUNT(id) AS total FROM pages WHERE user_id IN (
  SELECT id FROM users WHERE name LIKE '%keyword%'
) AND name LIKE '%keyword%';
```

***Here's how it works:***

The first query retrieves the count of pages that match the keyword and have an associated event that occurred after January 1, 2023. The second query retrieves the count of pages that match the keyword and are owned by a user whose name matches the keyword.

When we combine these two queries using UNION, we get two rows of data, one for each query. Each row contains a single column with the count of pages that matched the respective query.

So in the final result set, you will see two rows, each with a "total" column that contains the count of pages that matched the corresponding query.

If you only want a single row with the total count of pages that matched both conditions, you can wrap the entire query in an outer SELECT statement and use SUM to add up the counts from the two rows:

```sql
SELECT SUM(total) AS total_count FROM (
  SELECT COUNT(id) AS total FROM pages WHERE id IN (
    SELECT page_id FROM events WHERE date > '2023-01-01'
  ) AND name LIKE '%keyword%'
  UNION
  SELECT COUNT(id) AS total FROM pages WHERE user_id IN (
    SELECT id FROM users WHERE name LIKE '%keyword%'
  ) AND name LIKE '%keyword%'
) AS subquery;
```

This will give you a single row with the total count of pages that matched both conditions.

Comment: Can you explain how the `UNION` works, Actually the query works but I get two rows with two total values

Comment: @Ajith Please check the answer explanation updated

Comment: @ Ajimi I think total from the subquery is not getting correctly, It is actually sum up the two rows totals

Comment: @Ajith Please try below query :- SELECT SUM(total_count) AS total FROM (
  SELECT COUNT(P.id) AS total_count FROM pages P
    INNER JOIN events E ON E.page_id = P.id
    INNER JOIN users U ON U.id = P.user_id
    WHERE P.name LIKE '%keyword%' AND E.date > '2023-01-01'
  UNION
  SELECT COUNT(P.id) AS total_count FROM pages P
    INNER JOIN users U ON U.id = P.user_id
    WHERE P.name LIKE '%keyword%' AND U.name LIKE '%keyword%'
) AS subquery;

Comment: This is a completely different query, as OP's `events.date` criterion applies whether the `keyword` match is on `pages.name` or `users.name`. Also, any page matching both criteria would be counted twice.